# iOS:How to know which file takes much size-in-application in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I have third party project which uses following code this code is not all but it write big file(say recording) in app bundle how to find that file?

```
NSError *audioSessionError = nil;
    AVAudioSession *audioSession= [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&audioSessionError];
    [audioSession setMode:AVAudioSessionModeDefault error:&audioSessionError];
    [audioSession setPreferredSampleRate:16000.0f error:&audioSessionError];
    [audioSession setPreferredInputNumberOfChannels:1 error:&audioSessionError];
    [audioSession setActive:TRUE error:&audioSessionError];
    _sampleRate= [audioSession sampleRate];

    // make a capture session that uses the audio session
    _captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc]init];
    _captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480;
    _captureSession.automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession= NO;




 _startTimeMS = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000;

    dispatch_queue_t videoQueue = dispatch_queue_create("smmaProcessingQueueVideo", NULL);
    [_videoOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:videoQueue];

    dispatch_queue_t audioQueue = dispatch_queue_create("smmaProcessingQueueAudio", NULL);
    [_audioOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:audioQueue];
```

Same code for video, as well Now, this code write too big file(up to 2 GB) in app. Audio+Video,

I want to find & Delete that file.i tried

```
NSString *appFolderPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSLog(@"App Directory is: %@", appFolderPath);
NSLog(@"Directory Contents:\n%@", [fileManager directoryContentsAtPath: appFolderPath]);
```

how to do that? any help will much appreciated.

Comment: @EricD.Alright. Could you try for answer?

Comment: There is nothing in code that consumes that much memory!!

Comment: It's not possible a code file take so much memory after compilation

Comment: @David'mArm'Ansermot. not about code. about file written in app bundle somewhere i can get what file file to delete it.

Comment: If file written programmatically then it should be in documents directory or tempdirectory or in cachedirectory. Not in main bundle

Comment: if it recording file Is it written in .app files?

Comment: It's depends on you. You can store it in `documentdirectory` or in `tempDirectory`.

Comment: Generally we initialize recorder like `audioRecorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:soundFileURL settings:recordSetting error:&error];`.  `soundFileURL` is url from the path. so on this path recording file is stored

Comment: You should make tempdirectory to temprary store recordings and when you want to save, save it in document directory and clear temp directory periodically or whenever needed as mentioned in my answer. @AvijitNagare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clear `temp directory` by,

```
  NSArray* tmpDirectory = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:NSTemporaryDirectory() error:NULL];
for (NSString *file in tmpDirectory) {


    BOOL suc = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", NSTemporaryDirectory(), file] error:NULL];

    if (suc) {

        NSLog(@"done");
    }
    NSLog(@"file : %@%@",NSTemporaryDirectory(), file);
}
```

You can clear `cachedirectory` like,

```
         dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                                   NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];


    NSFileManager *manager1 = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSArray *filesArDirectory1 = [manager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:docsDir error:nil];

    NSError *err1;

    for (NSString *file2 in filesArDirectory1) {

        BOOL success = [manager1 removeItemAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", docsDir,file2] error:&err1];

        if (!success || err1) {
            NSLog(@"error description : %@",[err1 localizedDescription]);
            NSLog(@"failed2");

        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"Success2");
        }
        NSLog(@"files : %@",file2);

    }
```

Try to clear both this directory if it stores data. Check that your document directory stores big data then you need to manage that also.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: it work for that directory but it seems to be the data i want to delete is in .app directory. any idea?

Comment: .app directory means bundle i think and you don't have write permission on it. Check [Apple documentation for filesystem](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html)

Comment: You can drag and drop file to bundle and manually delete it by move to trash. Programmatically you can only read from it, can't write